# How to download osmdroid tiles on user end?

Tags: android, dictionary, offline, osmdroid, mapnik

I already successful to load map tiles from SD Card of **osmdroid (Mapnik)**

But now i want to give a option in my android app to download map tile that user want to use
mean map show online **user select a specific area and cashes it**  for his use 
i don't know how to do please help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the question points to. As far as I understand it, you have the user select an area - which is expressed in geographical coordinates - and then use these coordinates to calculate the tiles to be retrieved.

Under [Slippy map tilenames](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) in the OSM wiki there is a very good explanation how to do this:

> - Reproject the coordinates to the Mercator projection (from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857):
>
>   ```
>   x = lon
>   y = arsinh(tan(lat)) = log[tan(lat) + sec(lat)]
>   ```
>
>   (lat and lon are in radians)
> - Transform range of `x` and `y` to `0` – `1` and shift origin to top left corner:
>
>   ```
>   x = [1 + (x / π)] / 2
>   y = [1 − (y / π)] / 2
>   ```
> - Calculate the number of tiles across the map, `n`, using `2^zoom`
> - Multiply `x` and `y` by `n`. Round results down to give `tilex` and `tiley`.